# How to style breadcrums on xPage?

Tags: css, xpages

I use Bootstrap3 theme in my app. And seems there is no way to style your breadcrumb control. I want to make it like bootstrap style (see picture below). Putting just plain html/css code into xPage doesn't work. Seems xPage Bootstrap3 theme overrides it... Does anybody tried to create something similar?

[image]

These examples don't work on xPages:
https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/triangle-breadcrumbs-arrows

Comment: does anybody have an experience with styling xPage breadcrumb? I tried to disableTheme=true. It kinda help. But it disables the theme for entire page.

Comment: If I look at the default styling of breadcrumbs in bootstrap 3 and compare them with how they are generated in xpages with the extension library bootstrap theme then they are exactly the same (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#breadcrumbs) . If you use however the breadcrumb control from the extension library then you have a render problem, that is basically because the generated HTML differs from the expected HTML (divs are generated, not ordered lists). So my advice: try to develop a function that will generate the correct HTML and leave the breadcrumb control as past.